# Can i use same array variable to store image and video?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to get image and video from photo albums using uiimagepickercontroller and then show on tableview cell.

steps to display image and video on tableview cell is as below,

1. click photos button on UI
2. gallery open and select photo from gallery then save it on array1
3. display it on the first cell of table view
4. again click on the video button
5. gallery open and select video from gallery then save it on array1
   6.display it on the second cell of tableview

and so on, these steps not fix, we can click the first video button.

Note 1;
I'm making demo app like Facebook
Where users can post either image or video (but from photo album), and show on cell.
Note 2;
it runs proper but when I select first video and then select photo then I get error in cellforrowat indexpath method**Could not cast value of type 'UIImage' (0x7fff86f38430) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86d97bb0).** in else part.

my code is as below, (It's just reference, I have omitted code for avplayer and video selection from the gallery for simplicity)

```
        import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
        @IBOutlet weak var imageFromGallery: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
        
        var postCellArray = [Any]()
        var postMediaType : String = ""
        
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        
        @IBAction func getVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
            getVideosFromGallery()
        }
        @IBAction func getPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
            getPhotosFromGallery()
        }
        
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        
            pickerController.delegate = self
            pickerController.allowsEditing = true
            
        }
        
        func getVideosFromGallery(){
           
 if let selectedVideo : URL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
           postMediaType = "public.movie"
               postCellArray.append(selectedVideo)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.postTableView.reloadData()
                }

        }
        func getPhotosFromGallery(){
            pickerController.allowsEditing = false
            pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    
    
    }
    
    extension ViewController : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{
                
                postCellArray.append(pickedImage)
                tableview.reloadData()
            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource{
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return postCellArray.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
        
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
                 if postMediaType == "public.movie"{
                    postImageVideoCell.addSubview(postImageVideoCell.playerView)
                    postImageVideoCell.configure(postCellArray[indexPath.row] as! String)
    }
             else{
     //I get error here
                    postImageVideoCell.userPostImageVideo.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: (postCellArray[indexPath.row] as! String))
    
                }
          return postImageVideoCell
    }
    
    func configure(_ videoUrl: String)
        {
            guard let url = URL(string: videoUrl) else { return }
            self.url = url
            playerView.prepareToPlay(withUrl: url, shouldPlayImmediately: false)
        }
```

Comment: Yes you can but it is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how it’s bad idea , please tell us.

Comment: Because every time you want to get an element from the array you need to check what type it is.

Comment: Do you have any other way? @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Listen, this is a very vague question without any detailed information on what you are trying to do so no I do not have any detailed answer since it is impossible to have one. All I can say is that I would consider separating the objects by having two arrays

Comment: @JoakimDanielson
i have updated my question.
please kindly focus on dataSource array.

Comment: You could create a simple structs holding the media and a property saying if it is a move or an image and then have one array for that struct as your data source.

Comment: You should not keep images or videos in an array. You should keep strings, eg paths or asset identifiers.

Comment: @matt 
I'm beginner in iOS , do you mean AVAssest?

Comment: Could be, or maybe just the asset local identifier. Images are huge; an array of them will crash your app as it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Yes

Long Answer:

Arrays in swift don't have any types unless you specify them explicitly as a collection of certain types of objects.

You can do something as weird as this and it will still be possible.

```
let image = UIImage()
let video = AVAsset()

var array = [image, video]
```

or declare the array as a collection of `AnyObject`

```
var array = [AnyObject]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using the `struct` or `AnyObject` type as above suggestions. You can create an array of `enum` with associated values:

```
enum MediaType {
  case image(_: UIImage)
  case video(_: AVAsset)
}
var dataSource: [MediaType] = []

/// add data
dataSource.append(.image(imageData))
dataSource.append(.video(videoData))

// in cellForRowAt

switch item {
  case image(let image):
  // display image
  case video(let video):
 // display video
}
```

Comment: I have use this code of line
`postImageVideoCell.configure(postCellArray[indexPath.row] as! String). <br/> func configure(_ videoUrl: String)
    {
        guard let url = URL(string: videoUrl) else { return }
        self.url = url
        playerView.prepareToPlay(withUrl: url, shouldPlayImmediately: false)
    }`